# SharePoint 2013 - Create Dashboard for Action Item Tracker (From a List)

Tags: 2013, list, dashboard

I am trying to create a dashboard (with charts and such) for an action item tracker list (Open, Not Started, In Progress, Completed, and Cancelled items). The dashboard should include:

```
Number of Total Actions
Number of Open Actions
Number of Outstanding Actions
Are we meeting deadlines (for Due Date)?
```

The list is already created, but I'm still relatively new to SharePoint and am not sure what the best way is to go about making charts. Any guidance would be great!

Comment: Well, you could use any JavaScript/jQuery plugin to generate charts and make dashboard page. And yes, if you are new to SharePoint, then probably you should learn more first about the SharePoint required flow for your approach.

Comment: You can use the xml from the SharePoint 2010 Chart Web Part: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/b011e137-70eb-4092-b8e2-e5ed9a5ead7e/sharepoint-2013-how-do-i-chart-a-list?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSOM to read the data from lists and [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) to create the graphs. Sample: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/create-a-chart-using-chartjs-in-sharepoint-server-2013